# async/await: can't access array value of function directly

Tags: javascript, async-await

This works:

```js
var getArray = function(id) {
  return [1, 2];
}

console.log(getArray()[0]); // returns 1
```

This does not work:

```js
var getArray = async function(id) {
  return [1, 2];
}

console.log(await getArray()[0]); // syntax error
```

Why? How can I change the `async`/`await` syntax so it works?

Comment: You cannot use `await` outside of an `async function`. Wherever you call `getArray`, make that `async` as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution, it's very simple. 
Just wrap the await part with parentheses.

```
var first = (await getArray())[0];
```

Comment: Checked it out of curiosity but I can't see why it would work nor I can reproduce it - it still throws syntax errors at me. https://codesandbox.io/s/vpyqln4zl

Comment: "await" must always be wrapped with an async function. it works here perfectly: https://codesandbox.io/s/kw016lolvo

Comment: If you wrap it with async function, those parantheses are not necessary though...

Comment: no, they are necessary: this will throw undefined https://codesandbox.io/s/kw016lolvo

Comment: Ah, right. That's because you try to access `0` element before awaiting the result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `await` keyword in another `async` function to get the desired result via - `(await getArray())[0]`.

If you use `async` function not inside another `async` function, it must be used like simple Promise function with calling `then`.

```js
var getArray =  async function(id) {
    return [1,2];
}

getArray().then(res => console.log(res[0])).catch(err => {/* ... */});
```

If you want to use `await`, you need another wrapper `async` function which will do the logic there and will be just called. Also you can use `try/catch` within your function

```js
var getArray =  async function(id) {
    return [1,2];
}

async function printFirst() {
  try {
     const first = (await getArray())[0];
     console.log(first);
  } catch(e) {
  
  }
}

printFirst();
```

Comment: I want to use async/await, not .then

Comment: See the updated answer. Also read the answer attentively. I have written where you can use `await`

Comment: @SurenSrapyan Your should add a note about uncaught errors if you don't have a `.catch` set.

Comment: @RyanZim Thanks. It was not necessary in this example, but for the whole picture I added.

Comment: i'm wondering if there is a more elegant solution with fewer lines, like with synchronous code.

Comment: You can use `await` only in the `async` functions

Answer (score 0):

A clearer way to do it is via ES6 destructuring:

```js
const [ topBid ] = await getBids(symbol)

// ^^^ it's the same as:

const topBid = (await getBids(symbol))[0]
```

In case you need not the first element of an array, there're various destructuring patterns for different scenarios:

https://www.deadcoderising.com/2017-03-28-es6-destructuring-an-elegant-way-of-extracting-data-from-arrays-and-objects-in-javascript/